# How to access object with req.body in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to create a new survey and would like the user to enter their own question based on type of survey(Multiple Choice or True/False). I would like the user to enter the QuestionText but my schema is structured like this:

```html
// create a question model
let questionModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    "MC": 
    {
        "QuestionText": String,
        "Options": [String]
    },
    "TF":
    {
        "QuestionText": String,
        "Options": Boolean
    }
  }
);


// create a survey model
let surveyModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    "Title": String,
    "Type": [String],
    "Questions": [questionModel],
    "Answered": { type: Number, default: 0 }, // how many times users answered
    "DateCreated": String,
    "Lifetime": Number // Survey expiry in seconds
  },
  {
    collection: "surveys",
  }
);
```

I am unsure of how to access the QuestionText string in the "MC" object through req.body.Questions. This is what I have right now. Can anyone help me out?

```html
// POST route for processing Create Survey Page - CREATE
router.post("/create", (req, res, next) => {
  let newSurvey = Survey({
    Title: req.body.Title,
    Type: req.body.Type,
    Questions: req.body.Questions[0].MC.QuestionText,
  });

  Survey.create(newSurvey, (err, Survey) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      // refresh survey list
      res.redirect("/live-surveys");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
"Title": "Some Survey",
    "Type": ["MC"],
    "Questions": [{
        "MC": {
            "QuestionText": "Favorite Color?",
            "Options": ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
        }
    }],
    "Answered": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    },
    "DateCreated": "Date",
    "Lifetime": {
        "$numberInt": "20"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`req.body` needs to be parsed into json

```js
const parsedBody = JSON.parse(req.body)
parsedBody.Questions[0].MC.QuestionText // will now be accesible
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I converted the JSON , it is giving me this error now "Cannot convert object to primitive value"